# Why is my copy constructor not working with new invocation and has same memory address?

Tags: c++

Am i able to use a copy constructor with   the new keyword?  My code also shows the 2 obj pointers have the same memory address?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Person{

public:

    int age;

        Person() {     }
        Person(const Person& p ) : age(p.age) {        }

};
int main()
{

    Person *p = new Person();
    p->age = 15;

    Person *y = p;

    // Person *z = new Person(p); why no work???


    // p and y have the same memory addres??
    std::cout << p;
    std::cout << y;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Person *z = new Person(p); // why no work???
```

Because `p` is a pointer, not a `Person&`. You need to dereference it to get the object:

```
Person *z = new Person(*p);
//                     ^^
```

Comment: @runners3431 To follow up, of course y == p: you set the pointers equal. A pointer is a memory location, so it can be copied indefinitely. It is like having a million signs pointed towards Boston: there is still only one Boston.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking when you create new a pointer, that pointer  is created and gets a new memory address.  Forgot I have to do &p.

Answer (score 2):

A better main in almost all ways

```
int main()
{

Person p;
p.age = 15;

Person y(p);


std::cout << &p;
std::cout << &y;

return 0;
}
```

`new` is not your friend. `new` is the enemy of all that is RAII. Down with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Because p is a pointer.

Try

```
Person *z = new Person(*p);
```